# highlight active menu item, according to current page with jsp/jstl, no javascript

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, jsp-fragments

I am currently working on a site that uses [jsp](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html)
and [jstl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html). I like to highlight in the navbar the active tab with an active class used in [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), according to the current page, i found many ways ([thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html)) to get the result, but none with pure jstl and jsp. I came up with this solution:

> ${ pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith(' /... ') ? 'active' : " " }

but it doesn't work, the navbar.jspf file is located with the header.jspf in the todo.jsp file. **Everything works except of the active tab in the navigation**, thanks for help.

The header.jspf looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Add Todo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

The navigation.jspf looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border mb-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand p-2" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler m-2" type="button" data-
      toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-
      controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-
      label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item 
        ${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('/') ? 'active' : 
        ''}">
        <a class="nav-link p-3 " href="/login">Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item 
          ${pageContext.request.requestURI.endsWith('/list-todos') ? 
          'active' : 
          ''}">
        <a class="nav-link p-3 " href="/list-todos">Todos</a>
      </li>
   </div>
</nav>
```

The all including todo file looks like this:

```
  <%@ include file="fragments/header.jspf" %>
  <%@ include file="fragments/navigation.jspf" %>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Add Todo Page for ${name}</h2>
    ...........
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dang, as i supposed. Its possible with defining a modelAttribute in the controller for the specific page. And a jsp variable in the navbar.

In my case like this:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")
public class LoginController {

  @Autowired
  LoginService service;

  @RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showLoginPage(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("activeLogin", "active");
    return "login";
  }
}
```

The Navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light border-bottom mb-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand p-2" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler m-2" type="button" data-
   toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-
   controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-
   label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item ${activeLogin}">
       <a class="nav-link p-3 " href="/login">Home</span></a>
     </li>
     .........
   </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<c:set var="pagina" value="${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}" />
```

and in your HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item ${pagina.endsWith('/') ? 'active' : ''} ${pagina.endsWith('/index') ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="${ctx}/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ${pagina.endsWith('/menu') ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="${ctx}/menu">Menu</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item ${pagina.endsWith('/servizi') ? 'active' : ''}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="${ctx}/servizi">Servizi</a>
                </li>
<!-- ... more items -->
</ul>
```

and in your CSS

```
nav li.active a {color: red; font-weight:bold;}
```